# Help identifying the font

Tags: fonts, amsmath

Does anyone happen to know the font for x_1, x_2, and p in the graph?[image]

Thanks!

Comment: if you have a pdf you can see exactly which fonts are used. from an image we can only guess

Comment: Peraphs is times new roman or similar.

Comment: What is the title at least of the book.

Comment: Jiawei Yang what is please the title of the book :-))))? We are waiting for you.

Comment: It's actually an academic paper, this one: https://www.thomasepper.com/papers/RaFM.pdf